# Wordpress site user accounts

Tags: wordpress, authentication, content-management-system

I am new to web development. I am trying to build a site using wordpress as a cms. As such i want to know whether there is any way to create user accounts, so that people can register with the site and login. We would have an online store and we would like users to be able to save and view orders.

I have seen buddy press, but it only works with some themes. Is there any other option available?

Thanks in advance,
cpv

Answer (score 1):

You can add one of the free plugins such as "Login Logout". This is the one I am currently using and it lets new users register for accounts.

You need to search for it in your plugins tab in wordpress, then install and activate it. Then you need to go to your Widgets tab and include it. Then it should run on your website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Wordpress has user management, I suggest you play around with wordpress to understand how it works. Download a few e-commerce plugins or user management plugins and see how it all works.

Buddy press just uses the same user management that wordpress has.

I'm sure the [wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) is a good place to look for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am pretty new to web development, and have only worked with plain html sites before. I will definitely look into the wp documentation.